# (Angular 12) The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I have the following dynamic import code to import a js library at runtime:

```
export class AuthService {
    constructor() {
        import('https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js').then(result => {
            console.log(result)
        })
    }
}
```

However when I try to build/serve the Angular project I get:

> external "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" - Error: The target
> environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not
> possible to use external type 'module' within a script
> Did you mean to build a EcmaScript Module ('output.module: true')?

In addition, vs-code highlights the `import` with the following:
[image]

I tried adding `"type": "module"` in `package.json` and `"module": "ESNext"` in `tsconfig.json`, but with no luck.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic imports only works since ES2020. Please, check your tsconfig.json in order to know what version is your target.

Comment: I tried changing the target to ```ES2020```/```ES2021```/```ESNext```, still doesn't work

Comment: Yeah not working for me